# Chrome dev tools: Origin of style without file name?

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

[image: Annotated screen shot of Chrome developer tools]

For the style of `div#at4-share`, there is no file name shown, in Chrome 30.0.

*Where may the style come from?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can see it on the screenshot you shown:

```
<style>(...)div#at4-share {padding-right:16px;}</style>
```

exactly 8 lines below the highlighted line.

it's inline in the document.